# Adding colour to specific countries in a world map using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a plot of a world map wusing ggplot in which USA, Canada, and Brazil are in red.

This is what I have tried

```
thismap = map_data("world")

ggplot(thismap, aes(long, lat, group=group))+geom_polygon(fill="white", colour="gray")+
  ggtitle("Map of World")
```

But, I could not obtain those countries in red

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. I add a column to the df where I set the colors. Inside `ggplot` map this column on the `fill` aestehtic(!!). To get the right colors use `scale_fill_identity`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

thismap = map_data("world")

# Set colors
thismap <- mutate(thismap, fill = ifelse(region %in% c("Brazil", "Canada", "USA"), "red", "white"))

# Use scale_fiil_identity to set correct colors
ggplot(thismap, aes(long, lat, fill = fill, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour="gray") + ggtitle("Map of World") + 
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: My pleasure. If you want do me a favor: Mark the question as answered. Besides giving me some (extra) credit it shows others with a similar problem that the solution worked and removes the question from the queue of questions still waiting for an answer.

Comment: What is the theme you have with the gray squares? In my RStudio I get just white as background. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelGoldstein. That's the default ggplot2 theme called `theme_grey`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a newbie :) How can I list all the themes?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein For the themes included in ggplot2 see https://ggplot2-book.org/polishing.html#themes. But there are much more provided by extension packages, e.g. via the `ggthemes` package: https://yutannihilation.github.io/allYourFigureAreBelongToUs/ggthemes/

Comment: Not sure if I should open a new question. But how to make the countries have different randomly assigned colors and not just one?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein. Define the color palette e.g. `colors <- scales::hue_pal()(10)` are the first ten default ggplot2 colors. Then you could do `thismap <- mutate(thismap, fill = ifelse(region %in% c("Brazil", "Canada", "USA"), sample(colors, 3), "white"))` where `sample(colors, 3)` randomly picks 3 colors for the 3 countries from the color palette.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. And to make the non-highlighted countries and the borderlines separating them the opposite colors (grey for countries filling and white for borderlines)? Can't figure this out ´(with geom_polygon(colour="white")´ I get white borderlines, but can't seem to find the color option for the non-highlighted  countries. Edited: I realize I must change the "white" in the same vector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232724/discussion-between-emmanuel-goldstein-and-stefan).